# Inheritance in c++. Why is it wrong?

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax, constructor, initialization

```
class Human 
{
    protected:
        string name;
    public:
        Human () : name ("Jim") {}
        Human (string n) : name (n) {}
};

class Adult : public Human
{
    private:
        string passportId;
    public:
        Adult ()// : name ("Eric"), passportId ("N0123") - *THIS IS ERROR* 
        {
            // this is ok
            name = "Eric";  
            passportId = "N0934956";
        }

        Adult (string n, string id)// : name(n), passportId(id) *THIS IS ERROR*
        { 
            // this is ok
            name = n;
            passportId = id;
        }
};
```

So we have base class **Human** and derived class **Adult**.
in the code (where is the implementation of constructor) you can see comment lines.

Why is it wrong to use such initialization in this situation?

```
Adult (string n, string id) : name(n), passportId(id) {} // *THIS IS ERROR*
```

Comment: This is due to how creation of objects work in c++; the father is created before the child, and here youre trying to init the fathers member before its instantiated

Comment: note what you wrote!! Adult (string n, string id) : name(name), passportId(id) {}  *name(name)* change it to n

Comment: Adult () : name ("Eric"), passportId ("N0123") {}
Adult (string n, string id) : name(n), passportId(id) { }

Comment: @Infested yup, right, but error is not because of it

Comment: @hofmn correct, but i still say my first comment is the answer.

Comment: @PeterWood Passport ID, it's example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct form is:

```
Adult(string n, string id) : Human(n), passportId(id) {}
```

The initialization list is for initializing base classes and your own members. You don't initialize your bases' members, they do that themselves.

Comment: Looking at this from a higher-level perspective, `Adult` has no business dictating [nor, in some similar cases, even _knowing about_] how `Human`'s properties are arranged/constructed/populated/named/distributed. `Human` should be entirely responsible for their management, and that is what the `Human` constructor is for (as demonstrated in this answer).

Answer (score 3):

Using an initializer list you can only initialize your own member variables.

You have to use the `Human` constructor in the initializer list:

```
Adult (string n, string id)
    : Human(n), passportId(id)
    {}
```

Answer (score 3):

The base class is being constructed before the derived class so you won't be able to instantiate the base class' members in the initialization list.

However, you can call the base class' constructor in the initialization list like this

```
Adult() : Human("Eric"), passportId("N0123") { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before executing the member-initialization-list of `Adult`, the base class default-constructor is invoked and executed. During the base class subobject initialization, the member `name` (which is a member of the base class) is constructed (and initialized). That means, by the time the member initialization list of the derived class is executed, `name` already exists, which is why your program is ill-formed.

What you should be doing is : select the appropriate base class constructor so as to initialize `name` properly. Here is how you do it:

```
Adult (string n, string id) : Human(n), passportid(id) {}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Member initialiser lists (that is, the initialisers after `:` in a constructor) can only initialise base classes and members of the constructor's class. Initialising members of a base class is the job of the base class's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because you try to access a member of an object that has not been constructed yet. What you can do is

```
class Human 
{
    protected:
        string name;
    public:
        Human () : name ("Jim") {}
        Human (string n) : name (n) {}
};

class Adult : public Human
{
    private:
        string passportId;
    public:
        Adult () : Human ("Eric"), passportId ("N0123") 
        {
        }

        Adult (string n, string id) : Human(n), passportId(id)
        { 
        }
};
```

That works, because it instructs the compiler to create the base class part of your object with the given values. Later in the code - as you have done already within the constructor - you can access the protected members.

Answer (score 0):

Because your derived class `Adult` contains `Human` as an object and you have to call its constructor in order to create it. When your `Adult` object dies, the destructors are called in reverse order. First `Adult`'s destructor then `Human`'s destructor.

Answer (score 0):

In the first initialisation:

```
Adult ()// : name ("Eric"), passportId (N0123) - *THIS IS ERROR*
```

you probably forgot the `"` around the passportId, and on the second:

```
Adult (string n, string id)// : name(name), passportId(id) *THIS IS ERROR*
```

I think you mixed up `n` and `name`, and also, looks like you should rather call the parent constructor like so:

```
Adult (string n, string id) : Human(n), passportId(id)
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you mix up name and n?

```
Adult (string n, string id) : name(n), passportId(id) {}
```

Comment: That's not the problem here.

Comment: that actually will give the same error. You should validate your code before posting it if possible.